# On map ready callbacks returning null

Tags: java, android, google-api

I am trying to make a google api for my app to show google maps on my apps but i keep getting this error
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.123.1234/com.123.1234.RideHailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference**

this is the map activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ride_hail);
        final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        assert mapFragment != null;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

When we call `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` , you may notice the word `Async`, it means we might not get the GoogleMap reference immediately.

Mostly you will get `null`. so `assert mapFragment != null;` will throw the error

You have to implement the callback of `OnMapReadyCallback#onMapReady` to get GoogleMap reference instead of null.

You can also create a GoogleMap example from Android Studio, and you will see:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}
```

Comment: So how do i fix it i dont get it

Comment: As said, you need to ensure that you use `mMap` after `onMapReady` was called.